# Getting 403(Forbidden) error on get Request from cloudFlare

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-s3, cloudflare, cloudflare-apps

I have an image uploaded to an S3 bucket, and I want to access that image via Cloudflare (CDN). When I attempt to view the image by entering the URL in a browser or using Postman, I can see the image without any issues.

**However, when I try to fetch it using Java in a Spring Boot application, I encounter a 403 error.**

I tried 3 ways to fetch image

1.

```
Image.getInstance(imageUrl)
```

2. ```
             RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
             HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
             headers.set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
             HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
             byte[] imageData = restTemplate.exchange(imageUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class).getBody();
   ```
3. ```
             URL url = new URL(logoPath);
             URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
             InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
             FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("image.png");
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             int bytesRead;
             while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                 outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
             }
             inputStream.close();
             outputStream.close();
   ```

In approach 1&3 I'm getting 401(Forbidden) .
In approach 2 , getting 301

What  can i do to resolve this issue ?

**I want to fetch this image to directly use in File .**

Answer (score 3):

I solved this error by adding a " user agent " while creating connection or headers.

**I also tried with adding multiple user agent but it didn't work for me .
Try to add only one user Agent .**

```
          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ");
          HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
          byte[] imageData = restTemplate.exchange(imageUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class).getBody();
```